# Installing Tensorflow on mac m1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, apple-m1

I am using PyCharm and in the Python Interpreter I install my packages. In other words

```
In Pycharm: from Python 3.9 venv --> Interpreter Settings --> Install Package: Tensorflow (+) --> Search for Package --> Install
```

I almost got anything I want (numpy, scipy, pandas, even torch!). However, I tried to install Tensorflow and I get the following ERROR:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

So, I tried using the shell and it is already installed in my `pip list` with the version `2.4.0` as of today.

Since I am using a `virtual env in PyCharm`, is there a way that I can solve the error and have the package installed? OR how can I migrate the installed packages from my pip to this venv?

If you are an M1 user you would already know that working on apps is a headache with the new silicon apple Mac.

I look forward to some help and suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: go ask in the tensorflow repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, at the time of posting this issue, tensorflow does not support `Python 3.9` and only works for `3.8`.

Further details are provided [#47151](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47151)