# Cannot import TensorFlow on Mac M1

Tags: macos, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a shell script on Mac OS M1, but it keeps giving me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I followed the instructions from here: https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706.

Although I now can import it manually in python:

```
(mlp) sarah@Air-Sarah AIR % python 
Python 3.8.11 (default, Aug 16 2021, 12:04:33) 
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'2.8.0'
```

my error in shell remains the same.

I also tried to install it with https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos. Nothing changed.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201657/installing-tensorflow-on-mac-m1)
it says that Python version has to be 3.8 for TensorFlow to be imported, but mine is 3.8.

What else can I do?

Comment: I've been able to address this issue following the [installation guides provided in the Washington University of St. Louis course T81-558:Applications of Deep Neural Networks](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install). There is a new guide added for some semesters, so you'll want to find the newest file in that folder.

Comment: Can you report this in Github as an bug . I was able to replicate this issue in Python 3.8 but was getting resolved with Python 3.9 in my local machine.